# Arduinoに磁石を近づけた時にUnityのcubeを動かしたい

Tags: unity3d, arduino

http://deviceplus.jp/hobby/entry044/
ここのサイトを参考にArduino回転計を作成しました。この回転計で磁石を使って回転数を図った時にUnity上のcubeを回転数におうじて進ませたいのですが方法がわかりません。
ArduinoとUnityの連携はUniduinoという有料アセットを利用してできました。

[image: Unity]

[image: Arduino]

Answer (score 2):

Serial.printで、BD7411G Sampleと表示されなくてはなりませんが、何も出ていないので、pinの接続が間違えているなど、初期化ができていない状態と見受けます。私ならば、PIN番号を変更して試したいところです。(あと、bd7411.initの前に、Serial.print("Start...")とでも入れてみて、そもそもコードが動いているのかを知りたいです。)

Comment: 返信遅くなって申し訳ございません。おかげさまで解決しました